# Trying to implement own function in an existing GitHub project

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

```js
L.interpolatePosition = function(p1, p2, duration, t) {
    var k = t/duration;
    k = (k > 0) ? k : 0;
    k = (k > 1) ? 1 : k;
    return L.latLng(p1.lat + k * (p2.lat - p1.lat),
        p1.lng + k * (p2.lng - p1.lng));
};

L.Marker.MovingMarker = L.Marker.extend({

    //state constants
    statics: {
        notStartedState: 0,
        endedState: 1,
        pausedState: 2,
        runState: 3
    },

    options: {
        autostart: false,
        loop: false,
    },

    initialize: function (latlngs, durations, options) {
        L.Marker.prototype.initialize.call(this, latlngs[0], options);

        this._latlngs = latlngs.map(function(e, index) {
            return L.latLng(e);
        });

        if (durations instanceof Array) {
            this._durations = durations;
        } else {
            this._durations = this._createDurations(this._latlngs, durations);
        }

        this._currentDuration = 0;
        this._currentIndex = 0;

        this._state = L.Marker.MovingMarker.notStartedState;
        this._startTime = 0;
        this._startTimeStamp = 0;  // timestamp given by requestAnimFrame
        this._pauseStartTime = 0;
        this._animId = 0;
        this._animRequested = false;
        this._currentLine = [];
        this._stations = {};
    },

    isRunning: function() {
        return this._state === L.Marker.MovingMarker.runState;
    },

    isEnded: function() {
        return this._state === L.Marker.MovingMarker.endedState;
    },

    isStarted: function() {
        return this._state !== L.Marker.MovingMarker.notStartedState;
    },

    isPaused: function() {
        return this._state === L.Marker.MovingMarker.pausedState;
    },

    start: function() {
        if (this.isRunning()) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.isPaused()) {
            this.resume();
        } else {
            this._loadLine(0);
            this._startAnimation();
            this.fire('start');
        }
    },

    resume: function() {
        if (! this.isPaused()) {
            return;
        }
        // update the current line
        this._currentLine[0] = this.getLatLng();
        this._currentDuration -= (this._pauseStartTime - this._startTime);
        this._startAnimation();
    },

    pause: function() {
        if (! this.isRunning()) {
            return;
        }

        this._pauseStartTime = Date.now();
        this._state = L.Marker.MovingMarker.pausedState;
        this._stopAnimation();
        this._updatePosition();
    },

    stop: function(elapsedTime) {
        if (this.isEnded()) {
            return;
        }

        this._stopAnimation();

        if (typeof(elapsedTime) === 'undefined') {
            // user call
            elapsedTime = 0;
            this._updatePosition();
        }

        this._state = L.Marker.MovingMarker.endedState;
        this.fire('end', {elapsedTime: elapsedTime});
    },

    addLatLng: function(latlng, duration) {
        this._latlngs.push(L.latLng(latlng));
        this._durations.push(duration);
    },

    moveTo: function(latlng, duration) {
        this._stopAnimation();
        this._latlngs = [this.getLatLng(), L.latLng(latlng)];
        this._durations = [duration];
        this._state = L.Marker.MovingMarker.notStartedState;
        this.start();
        this.options.loop = false;
    },

    addStation: function(pointIndex, duration) {
        if (pointIndex > this._latlngs.length - 2 || pointIndex < 1) {
            return;
        }
        this._stations[pointIndex] = duration;
    },

    onAdd: function (map) {
        L.Marker.prototype.onAdd.call(this, map);

        if (this.options.autostart && (! this.isStarted())) {
            this.start();
            return;
        }

        if (this.isRunning()) {
            this._resumeAnimation();
        }
    },

    onRemove: function(map) {
        L.Marker.prototype.onRemove.call(this, map);
        this._stopAnimation();
    },

    _createDurations: function (latlngs, duration) {
        var lastIndex = latlngs.length - 1;
        var distances = [];
        var totalDistance = 0;
        var distance = 0;

        // compute array of distances between points
        for (var i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
            distance = latlngs[i + 1].distanceTo(latlngs[i]);
            distances.push(distance);
            totalDistance += distance;
        }

        var ratioDuration = duration / totalDistance;

        var durations = [];
        for (i = 0; i < distances.length; i++) {
            durations.push(distances[i] * ratioDuration);
        }

        return durations;
    },

    _startAnimation: function() {
        this._state = L.Marker.MovingMarker.runState;
        this._animId = L.Util.requestAnimFrame(function(timestamp) {
            this._startTime = Date.now();
            this._startTimeStamp = timestamp;
            this._animate(timestamp);
        }, this, true);
        this._animRequested = true;
    },

    _resumeAnimation: function() {
        if (! this._animRequested) {
            this._animRequested = true;
            this._animId = L.Util.requestAnimFrame(function(timestamp) {
                this._animate(timestamp);
            }, this, true);
        }
    },

    _stopAnimation: function() {
        if (this._animRequested) {
            L.Util.cancelAnimFrame(this._animId);
            this._animRequested = false;
        }
    },

    _updatePosition: function() {
        var elapsedTime = Date.now() - this._startTime;
        this._animate(this._startTimeStamp + elapsedTime, true);
    },

    _loadLine: function(index) {
        this._currentIndex = index;
        this._currentDuration = this._durations[index];
        this._currentLine = this._latlngs.slice(index, index + 2);
    },

    /**
     * Load the line where the marker is
     * @param  {Number} timestamp
     * @return {Number} elapsed time on the current line or null if
     * we reached the end or marker is at a station
     */
    _updateLine: function(timestamp) {
        // time elapsed since the last latlng
        var elapsedTime = timestamp - this._startTimeStamp;

        // not enough time to update the line
        if (elapsedTime <= this._currentDuration) {
            return elapsedTime;
        }

        var lineIndex = this._currentIndex;
        var lineDuration = this._currentDuration;
        var stationDuration;

        while (elapsedTime > lineDuration) {
            // substract time of the current line
            elapsedTime -= lineDuration;
            stationDuration = this._stations[lineIndex + 1];

            // test if there is a station at the end of the line
            if (stationDuration !== undefined) {
                if (elapsedTime < stationDuration) {
                    this.setLatLng(this._latlngs[lineIndex + 1]);
                    return null;
                }
                elapsedTime -= stationDuration;
            }

            lineIndex++;

            // test if we have reached the end of the polyline
            if (lineIndex >= this._latlngs.length - 1) {

                if (this.options.loop) {
                    lineIndex = 0;
                    this.fire('loop', {elapsedTime: elapsedTime});
                } else {
                    // place the marker at the end, else it would be at
                    // the last position
                    this.setLatLng(this._latlngs[this._latlngs.length - 1]);
                    this.stop(elapsedTime);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            lineDuration = this._durations[lineIndex];
        }

        this._loadLine(lineIndex);
        this._startTimeStamp = timestamp - elapsedTime;
        this._startTime = Date.now() - elapsedTime;
        return elapsedTime;
    },

    _animate: function(timestamp, noRequestAnim) {
        this._animRequested = false;

        // find the next line and compute the new elapsedTime
        var elapsedTime = this._updateLine(timestamp);

        if (this.isEnded()) {
            // no need to animate
            return;
        }

        if (elapsedTime != null) {
             // compute the position
            var p = L.interpolatePosition(this._currentLine[0],
                this._currentLine[1],
                this._currentDuration,
                elapsedTime);
            this.setLatLng(p);
        }

        if (! noRequestAnim) {
            this._animId = L.Util.requestAnimFrame(this._animate, this, false);
            this._animRequested = true;
        }
    }
});

L.Marker.movingMarker = function (latlngs, duration, options) {
    return new L.Marker.MovingMarker(latlngs, duration, options);
};
```

I’m still new with JS and I have this problem. I was working on a js that I got from GitHub
https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker. Its a project where you have animated markers moving from a to b. I trying to demonstrate a transport environment for my thesis and I wrote my own functions to it.

```
function train_station(number){
const countries_train = [];
countries_train[1] = [71, "Germany", "Munich", 48.1351, 11.582, "Train Stration", "Europe"]
countries_train[2] = [72, "England", "London", 51.5074, 0.1278, "Train Stration", "Europe"]
countries_train[3] = [73, "Belgium", "Antwerp", 51.2194, 4.4025, "Train Stration", "Europe"]
countries_train[4] = [74, "France", "Limoges", 45.8336, 1.2611, "Train Stration", "Europe"]
countries_train[5] = [75, "Portugal", "Porto", 41.1579, 8.6291, "Train Stration", "Europe"]
countries_train[6] = [76, "Romania", "Bucharest", 44.4268, 26.1025, "Train Stration", "Europe"]
countries_train[7] = [77, "Italy", "Milan", 45.4642, 9.19, "Train Stration", "Europe"]
return countries_train[number]}

function europe_island(number) {
const countries_island = [];
countries_island[1] = [21, "Iceland", "Reykjavik", 64.1466, 21.9426, "Island", "Europe"]
countries_island[2] = [22, "Ireland", "Dublin", 53.3498, 6.2603, "Island", "Europe"]
return countries_island[number]}

export {europe_core, europe_island, europe_uk, train_station, harbour, europe_scandinavia, international}
```

Thats my function. I have other function but the structure is the same and the js file I want to implement it in is this:

So, I was trying to implement my function in the script.js file from the GitHub link and every time I import a function of mine the script doesn’t

```js
var map = new L.Map('map', {
    zoom: 6,
    minZoom: 3,
});

var tileUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', layer = new L.TileLayer(tileUrl,
{
  attribution: 'Maps © <a href=\"www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  maxZoom: 18
});

map.addLayer(layer);

var parisKievLL = [[48.8567, 2.3508], [50.45, 30.523333]]

var londonParisRomeBerlinBucarest = [[51.507222, -0.1275], [48.8567, 2.3508],
    [41.9, 12.5], [52.516667, 13.383333], [44.4166, 26.1]]

var londonBrusselFrankfurtAmsterdamLondon = [[51.507222, -0.1275], [50.85, 4.35],
    [50.116667, 8.683333], [52.366667, 4.9], [51.507222, -0.1275]];

var barcelonePerpignanPauBordeauxMarseilleMonaco = [
    [41.385064, 2.173403],
    [42.698611, 2.895556],
    [43.3017, -0.3686],
    [44.837912, -0.579541],
    [43.296346, 5.369889],
    [43.738418, 7.424616]
];

map.fitBounds(londonParisRomeBerlinBucarest);

var marker1 = L.Marker.movingMarker(parisKievLL, [10000]).addTo(map);
L.polyline(parisKievLL).addTo(map);
marker1.once('click', function () {
    marker1.start();
    marker1.closePopup();
    marker1.unbindPopup();
    marker1.on('click', function () {
        if (marker1.isRunning()) {
            marker1.pause();
        } else {
            marker1.start();
        }
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        marker1.bindPopup('<b>Click me to pause !</b>').openPopup();
    }, 2000);
});

marker1.bindPopup('<b>Click me to start !</b>', {closeOnClick: false});
marker1.openPopup();

var marker2 = L.Marker.movingMarker(londonParisRomeBerlinBucarest, [3000, 9000, 9000, 4000], {autostart: true}).addTo(map);
   
L.polyline(londonParisRomeBerlinBucarest, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);
marker2.on('end', function () {
    marker2.bindPopup(message(), {closeOnClick: false})
        .openPopup();
});

var marker3 = L.Marker.movingMarker(londonBrusselFrankfurtAmsterdamLondon,
    [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000], {autostart: true, loop: true}).addTo(map);
marker3.loops = 0;
marker3.bindPopup('', {closeOnClick: false});

var marker4 = L.Marker.movingMarker([[45.816667, 15.983333]], []).addTo(map);
marker3.on('loop', function (e) {
    marker3.loops++;
    if (e.elapsedTime < 50) {
        marker3.getPopup().setContent("<b>Loop: " + marker3.loops + "</b>")
        marker3.openPopup();
        setTimeout(function () {
            marker3.closePopup();

            if (!marker1.isEnded()) {
                marker1.openPopup();
            } else {
                if (marker4.getLatLng().equals([45.816667, 15.983333])) {
                    marker4.bindPopup('Click on the map to move me !');
                    marker4.openPopup();
                }

            }

        }, 2000);
    }
});
map.on("click", function (e) {
    marker4.moveTo(e.latlng, 2000);
});

var marker5 = L.Marker.movingMarker(barcelonePerpignanPauBordeauxMarseilleMonaco, 10000, {autostart: true}).addTo(map);
marker5.addStation(1, 2000);
marker5.addStation(2, 2000);
marker5.addStation(3, 2000);
marker5.addStation(4, 2000);

L.polyline(barcelonePerpignanPauBordeauxMarseilleMonaco,
    {color: 'green'}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Leaflet.MovingMarker Demo Page </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Leaflet plugin to animate marker !">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Leaflet MovingMarker marker ewoken github animation">
    <meta name="author" content="Ewoken">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <h1> Demo of Leaflet.MovingMarker </h1>
    <section>
        <div id="map">
        </div>
    </section>
</main>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MovingMarker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

work anymore.

It shows that *"referenceerror L is not defined"* and if I do the "Import * as L from 'leaflet'" is says that *"referenceerror: window is not defined"*

I havent changed the code, it’s just the imports. As soon as I type import the variables in the script turn from purple to grey and dont work anymore.
Im using IntelliJ 2021 IDE Ultimate 2021

- I have the type:module in my dependencies so the Imports and exports work.
- I change it module on the html file as well
- I deleted the folder and reinstalled everything again

Thanks for your time and help guys.

Comment: pls post your code.
I've removed the green line and add code like this.

```// L.polyline(barcelonePerpignanPauBordeauxMarseilleMonaco,
//     {color: 'green'}).addTo(map);


function test(number){
    console.log(number);
    L.polyline(barcelonePerpignanPauBordeauxMarseilleMonaco,
    {color: 'purple'}).addTo(map);
}

test(1);```
worked perfect for me.

Comment: Please do not post code in scren-shots. If it is relevant include it as text into your question and format it as code.